# Python list concatenation with strings into new list

Tags: python

Im looking for the best way to take a list of stirngs, generate a new list with each item from the previous list concatenated with a specific string.

**Example sudo code**

```
list1 = ['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4']
string = '-example'
NewList = ['Item1-example','Item2-example','Item3-example','Item4-example']
```

**Attempt**

```
NewList = (string.join(list1))
#This of course makes one big string
```

Comment: NewList = [x + string for x in list1]

Comment: thanks for all the prompt responses. Although all the proposed answers are technically correct I prefered @eugene y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string concatenation in a list comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']
>>> string = '-example'
>>> [x + string for x in list1]
['Item1-example', 'Item2-example', 'Item3-example', 'Item4-example']
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a list, a list comprehension is usually the thing to do.

```
new_list = ["{}{}".format(item, string) for item in list1]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to list comprehension is using `map()`:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x+string,list1)
['Item1-example', 'Item2-example', 'Item3-example', 'Item4-example']
```

Note,  `list(map(lambda x: x+string,list1))` in Python3.

Answer (score 1):

concate list item and string

```
>>>list= ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']
>>>newList=[ i+'-example' for i in list]
>>>newList
['Item1-example', 'Item2-example', 'Item3-example', 'Item4-example']
```